# Is this still a problem with the spacewalk granola bar?

Tags: eva, food

During the Shuttle era, EVA suits had a holder for a granola bar, which gave astronauts something to snack on during long spacewalks.

> The food bar of compressed fruit, grain, and nuts is wrapped in edible rice paper, and its upper end extends into the helmet area near the crew member’s mouth. When hungry, the crew member bites the bar and pulls it upward before breaking off a piece to chew. In that manner, a small piece of the bar remains extended into the helmet for the next bite.  **It is necessary to eat the entire bar at one time, because saliva quickly softens the protruding food bar, making it mushy and impossible to break off.**
>
> http://www.nasa.gov/pdf/188963main_Extravehicular_Mobility_Unit.pdf

Is this still an issue today?  And do we have any data about how much of the granola bar gets eaten?

Comment: I have no additional knowledge but the EMUs are essentially the same as they were in shuttle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per a face-to-face conversation last week with a former NASA astronaut who's been in these EMU several times while in Earth orbit, he said that they no longer have food available in the EMU suits.  It ended up being too messy and not worth the hassle.  They still have water available, but no longer food.